# Закодировать-раскодировать str со своим паролем

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача простая: есть `str`, допустим:

```
"калининград"
```

есть мой пароль, например:

```
"mypass123"
```

нужно `"калининград"` закодировать в нечитаемый набор символов с учетом моего пароля, раскодировать символы можно только командой с моим паролем, например:

```
one = encode("калининград","mypass123")
>>>fsdtr33sdfd324sfsfr3
two = decode("fsdtr33sdfd324sfsfr3","mypass123")
>>>калининград
```

желательно в дзене Python, в несколько строк

Comment: Вам для учёбы или для реальной защиты чего-то?

Comment: @andreymal для реальной защиты

Comment: @babyborn реальной защиты алгоритмом в несколько строк не добиться.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev взять тот же готовый crypto, не?)

Comment: @andreymal это уже не несколько строк, а несколько строк вызова API библиотеки и сотни строк её реализации, не считая сишных биндингов.

Comment: @andreymal и ещё я не помню, чтобы хоть какой-нибудь стойкий алгоритм шифрования выдавал результат похожий на тот, что у автора в вопросе.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev предположу, что автору не очень принципиальны сотни строк реализации библиотеки, а то такими рассуждениями можно и до миллионов строк ОС дойти)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шифрование `XOR` + `hex`:

```
def crypto_xor(message: str, secret: str) -> str:
    new_chars = list()
    i = 0

    for num_chr in (ord(c) for c in message):
        num_chr ^= ord(secret[i])
        new_chars.append(num_chr)

        i += 1
        if i >= len(secret):
            i = 0

    return ''.join(chr(c) for c in new_chars)


def encrypt_xor(message: str, secret: str) -> str:
    return crypto_xor(message, secret).encode('utf-8').hex()


def decrypt_xor(message_hex: str, secret: str) -> str:
    message = bytes.fromhex(message_hex).decode('utf-8')
    return crypto_xor(message, secret)


text = "калининград"
key = "mypass123"

encrypted = encrypt_xor(text, key)
print(encrypted)
# d197d189d18bd199d18ed18bd08cd081d1b3d19dd18d

print(decrypt_xor(encrypted, key))
# калининград

print(decrypt_xor("d197d189d18bd199d18ed18bd08cd081d1b3d19dd18d", key))
# калининград
```

---

**PS.**

**Sergey Gornostaev** уже предлагал XOR'ом решить и его реализация XOR через `cycle` аналогичная тому, что в моем ответе:

```
from itertools import cycle

def crypt(msg, key):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(c) ^ ord(k)) for c, k in zip(msg, cycle(key)))
```

Поэтому, для сокращения кода лучше использовать `crypt` вместо `crypto_xor`

Comment: Больше функциональщины: `''.join(map(chr, starmap(xor, zip(map(ord, text), map(ord, cycle(key))))))`

Comment: @mkkik, ... богу функциональщины :D

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее часто применяемой функцией для шифрования, является функция md5() из библиотеки hashlib, которая шифрует строку с помощью алгоритма MD5.
Она используется для шифрования паролей, так как не существует алгоритма для дешифровки.

Сделал для вас простой пример:

```
import hashlib


base_password = 'mypass123'


password_hash = hashlib.md5(bytes(base_password, 'utf-8'))
password_encode = password_hash.hexdigest()
input_password = input('Введите пароль: ')
input_password_hash = hashlib.md5(bytes(input_password, 'utf-8'))
input_password_encode = input_password_hash.hexdigest()
if password_encode == input_password_encode:
    print("Пароль правильный")
else:
    print("Пароль неправильный")
```

Только в вашем случае необходимо хранить пароль не в открытом виде, а в зашифрованном. 
И соответственно уже с этим ключом сравнивать пароль, который будет введен.

Пароль 'mypass123' в этом случае, будет выглядеть вот так 'bad65492ede82b516379ec0289a7335d'.

Получается финальный код будет выглядеть вот так:

```
import hashlib


base_password = 'bad65492ede82b516379ec0289a7335d'


input_password = input('Введите пароль: ')
input_password_hash = hashlib.md5(bytes(input_password, 'utf-8'))
input_password_encode = input_password_hash.hexdigest()
if base_password == input_password_encode:
    print("Пароль правильный")
else:
    print("Пароль неправильный")
```

Comment: https://yandex.ru/turbo?text=https%3A%2F%2Ftproger.ru%2Farticles%2Fmd5-hacking%2F&d=1 не так уж это и безопасно

Comment: Кодирование, шифрование и хеширование разные вещи :) автор хочет второе, а у вас третье

Comment: @gil9red ну тут вопрос только в том, какая у автора цель. Мой способ так же даст защиту. Но тут нужно понимать от кого защищаемся :) Ну и так же, хочется добавить, что мой способ максимально прост для понимания. Собственно, для чего я и старался :) Ваш способ мощнее, да. Плюсанул :)

Comment: @Alan564, смотрите, автору нужно сделать так, чтобы исходная строка изменилась до неузнаваемости и при этом ее можно было после вернуть. У вас используется хеширование, а не шифрование (прошу слово шифрование заменить на хеширование). Хеширование подразумевает изменение данных с помощью хеш-функции. И да, пароли принято хранить не в чистом виде, а в виде хешей. Но, 1) md5 считается устаревшим и уязвимым, лучше использовать sha1 2) пароли в чистом виде не хешируют, их солят -- т.е. перед хешем добавляют какую-нибудь строку. Это нужно чтобы сложнее было получить исходную строку

Comment: @Alan564, продолжаю комментарий: Слышали про радужные таблицы? Берем список наиболее часто используемых паролей, хешируем его популярными хеш-функциями: sha1, md5, и т.д. Берем утащенную базу паролей и ищем хеши из украденной базы в своей радужной таблицы, и получаем чистый пароль. Но если пароли были "соленые", то задача получения чистого пароля станет нереальной. Кст, погуглите ваш хеш из вопроса, сразу же получите чистый пароль: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=md5+bad65492ede82b516379ec0289a7335d

Comment: @gil9red Вы крутой :) Узнал для себя что-то новое. Спасибо! Насчет того, что вы говорите, есть даже вот такой сайт http://www.md5decrypt.org/

Comment: @Alan564, рад, что мой комментарий был полезен :)